# Android - Launching widget manager from market

Tags: android, android-manifest, widget

I'm pretty sure this is a newb question but I can't quite figure it out.

I have a simple application which works as a widget, I use an ImagesWidgetProvider for all widget operations and once installed, it is not displayed as amongst the other applciations and therefore the 'open' button is greyed out once user has downloaded this.

The problem is, some users fail to read the app description that clearly explains how to add a widget to their homescreen which results in 1 star ratings along with 'doesn't work/open' comments.

All frustration with users aside, is there something I can do to make the widget selection menu (long press homescreen > widget) pop up when they click 'open' from the market without having to make them have an new app in the app menu?

I'm sure its just something I need to add to the manifest. When installing the app the console states

```
[2011-08-09 03:40:43 - com.xxx.xxx] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-08-09 03:40:43 - com.xxx.xxx] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. Best you can do is have a main activity that shows up in the launcher and opens up a help page explaining how to install the widget.

Comment: That may actually be a better option anyway, thanks Nikolay. Just to confirm, through this method the user MUST have an icon/access to the 'help' page displayed along side the rest of there app yeah?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the rest of the app', but if you only have a widget, the main activity (the one that shows up as an icon in the launcher), can just show a help page. If it does other things as well, you can set it up to only show the help page the first time it's run, and/or have a button/menu to display help at any time.

Comment: Damn, typo. "Rest of their apps", but I think you've answered the question. Currently, there is no main activity so there is no icon in the app selecion menu - I'd prefer to keep it this way, so to confirm, I definitely cannot launch the widget selection screen from the markets 'open' button' without having the widget show up in the apps menu? Thanks you

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. You can in fact do this: if you don't add the 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' category to the main activity, it won't show app in the launcher. You will still be able to open it via the Market's 'Open' button. Whether that's easier for users to find is another matter :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response - though I still can't work out what I'm supposed to add to the manifest to open the widget manager from the market but without it appearing in the launcher?

Comment: An activity with the intent filter below. Note the lack of the LAUNCHER category:`<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>`