# Provide "open" in Market without icon in Launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, icons, google-play, launcher

my app is a widget and without main launcher activity people cannot start it from the Market after installing the app; the "open" button just does not show up. How can I enable people to open the app from the Market, so that I can tell them that the app is a widget, but I do not want my app to show up in the launcher? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a duplicate question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990916/android-launching-widget-manager-from-market), in the thread Nikolay Elenkov said that you can create a main activity like below, then it will not be shown in the launcher but it can still be launched when the user select the "Open" button. In the activity you can tell the user how to install your widget.

```
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <!-- don't show the app icon in the launcher
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```